# How to remove windows user account folder using C#?

Tags: c#, windows

I have application which creates some windows user accounts, on uninstallation I remove the Windows User Account, but the folder for that user remains there (For example C:\Documents and Settings\UserName\"

How can I remove that folder using C#?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something along the lines of this?

```
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData));
dir = dir.Parent.Parent.Parent;
DirectoryInfo[] userDirs = dir.GetDirectories(userName);

foreach (DirectoryInfo userDir in userDirs)
{
    userDir.Delete(true);
}
```

Comment: That only works for the currently logged in user. The actual folder created for another account is far more difficult to come by.

Comment: Agree, but they all reside in the same directory (e.g. C:\Documents and Settings\\), don't they? The Parent.Parent.Parent bit moves up to that common directory, then the GetDirectories(userName) bit moves to the relevant subdirectory. Agree though, this could be improved!

Comment: It works with small change:
dir = dir.Parent.Parent.Parent;

dir = dir.Parent.Parent;
We need to go up only 2 folders :-) Thanks

Comment: This will only work if you are using an admin account on the machine. An ordinary user account should not have access to the folder for other accounts (on a properly secured machine).

Comment: I think that can be assumed given the nature of what is trying to be achieved :-)